# Can't install software due to "Authentication service is not available" error

Tags: lubuntu, policykit

Yesterday I installed Lubuntu 14.04 alternative iso on an old XP laptop. The partition and install went well. There are, however some issues with security, or my ability to add users and software. I installed the Software center from the Aptitude Package Manager, which went Ok, but I cannot download software due to insufficient privilege.

```
Authentication Error, Software can't be installed or removed because the
authentication service is not available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: 
('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.28'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
```

I did download Firefox successfully using Terminal. I wanted to add users so did a `sudo` for `gnome-system-tools`, which installed, but I cannot add users nor update software due to lack of authentication. For example the Software Updater says: `You are not allowed to perform this action. You don't have the required privileges to perform this action.`

All the issues seem to indicate that Lubuntu does not have sufficient privileges to update software/users, but I am logged on as the one and only user and therefore admin person.

Please tell me what I did wrong. The old Dell laptop does work much faster and better than using XP. Thanks.

Addendum Friday April 18 2014
So I tried to reinstall Lubuntu 14.04 LTS alternative iso from scratch from my USB. I realized that though I configured my Dell Inspiron 6000 500M Ram to boot from USB, when I selected "Install Lubuntu" I would get to an install step where it asked me to mount the CD-Rom. As I was using a USB I was forced to abort the install. Instead I burned a Lubuntu 14.04 LTS alternative iso CD and installed from it. While the laptop still booted from the USB when the install asked to mount the CD I provided the install CD and the install was successful.

Firefox was provided default and runs well. Using the Synaptic Package Manager I installed Chromium, which runs like a dog.

Summary: Lubuntu 14.04 LTS alternative iso will only install using a CD for my old laptop.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Chromium and not Firefox came with lubuntu 14.04, and I'm not sure why. Chromium worked well but I wanted Firefox, which is what I'm using now.

Answer (score 0):

> I am logged on as the one and only user and therefore admin person.

Lubuntu doesn't work that way: ALL users are "users". As you have already seen, you sometimes need to use `sudo` to perform certain actions (this requires password); alternatively, you can become "root" to perform actions without needing to use `sudo`.

Have a look at the [Ubuntu documentation on "root" and `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) (which includes a link for information on adding users) and/or [Wikipedia on `sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) if this is new to you. To repeat: simply being the first or even only "user" does not mean you avoid having to authenticate to do certain things to your system.

Comment: Thanks for the info on Root. I had forgotten this, though it is key to ubuntu. How can I get Software Center to act with the privilege of Root, just like I have sudo privilege in Terminal. I currently cannot add software other than in terminal.

Comment: I don't use the Lubuntu software centre (I use Ubuntu), but it *should* ask you to authenticate and proceed with the install: that's how it works on Ubuntu, anyway. I don't know if Lubuntu still includes the "[Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)", but that is also a painless way to install software packages.

Comment: I've used Xubuntu for a couple of years. Lubuntu 14.04 alternative did not come with either the Software Center nor Synaptic Package manager, but with Aptitude Package Manager, which is text based. I find it hard to use. Why is the Software Center not asking me to authenticate?

Comment: Maybe you could get some help from [their IRC channel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Support#Live_Chat)?

Comment: I have nothing on this laptop. Maybe I should do a reinstall of Lubuntu 14.04 alternative and do another clean install? Would it fix itself?